# How to insert each element of a character list into a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

How can I insert each element of a character list into a matrix (mxn)
I have this code in python

```
key = raw_input('Key: ')
text = raw_input('Text: ')
text_c = list(text)
while ' ' in text_c:
  text_c.remove(' ')     
columns = len(key)              
rows = int(math.ceil(float(len(text_c)) / float(len(key))) )
matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        matrix[i].append(None)
```

Now, I want to insert each element from the text_c to the matrix. No matter if that matrix does not fill. 
How can I do this. Thanks 
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample in- and output snippet and make your code fully runnable? For example `tabla` is not defined properly in the code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, tabla is matrix. I already correct it

Comment: And what about the sample in-/output?

Comment: In addition: What does `key` do?

Comment: Key gives a number of columns of matrix.  I try to make a cryptographic algorithm. A user write a key, and a text string. The program calculate the number of rows and columns based on those elements.

Comment: For example: if a user writes key: 'HOLA' and text: 'this is a string', so the program print the matrix [[t,h,i,s],[i,s,a,s],[t,r,i,n],[g,None,None,None]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining some list comprehensions as follows:

```
number_columns = 6
sample_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh'

l = [list(sample_string[i:i+number_columns]) for i in range(0, len(sample_string), number_columns)]
matrix = [s if len(s) == number_columns else s+[None]*(number_columns-len(s)) for s in l]
```

giving for `matrix`:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
 ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
 ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
 ['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x'],
 ['y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', None, None]]
```

First of all we slice the `sample_string` to substrings of the desired length (number of columns) which are converted to lists after slicing.

In the sample code I provided `sample_string` is not evenly divisible by the given `number_colums` meaning that the last list of the substring `efgh` does not have the desired length of `number_columns`. In order to get that fixed we need to check if the length of each list is as desired. If not, we are appending the needed amount of `None` elements.

In order to get rid of any spaces we need to extend the code by

```
sample_string = sample_string.replace(' ', '')
```

which would replace any spaces with an empty string. So

```
number_columns = 6
sample_string = 'this is a sample string'

sample_string = sample_string.replace(' ', '')

l = [list(sample_string[i:i+number_columns]) for i in range(0, len(sample_string), number_columns)]
matrix = [s if len(s) == number_columns else s+[None]*(number_columns-len(s)) for s in l]
```

would lead to

```
[['t', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's'],
 ['a', 's', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l'],
 ['e', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n'],
 ['g', None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept my answer in order to mark your question as solved.

Comment: Done! Thanks, I´m new in the site